# Why no line drawn when use dot with psmatrix?

Tags: pstricks, graphs, psmatrix

I am trying to draw a signal flow graph with \psmatrix where each node is just a dot. However \ncline does not seem to work when mnode is set to dot

```
$
\psmatrix[colsep=1cm,rowsep=1cm,mnode=dot]
1&2&3&4&5 \\
&2&3&4 \\
&2&3&4
\psset{arrows=->,nodesep=1pt}
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\ncline{1,1}{1,2}
\ncline{1,2}{1,3}^{-z^{-1}}
\endpsmatrix
$
```

But if I change mnode to circle, the lines appear again!

Please help! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, if you move the line connections outside of the `psmatrix` environment:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
$\psmatrix[colsep=1cm,rowsep=1cm,mnode=dot]
1&2&3&4&5 \\
&2&3&4 \\
&2&3&4
\endpsmatrix
\psset{arrows=->,nodesep=1pt, shortput=nab}
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\ncline{1,1}{1,2}
\ncline{1,2}{1,3}^{-z^{-1}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]